# manifest.srcFile causing contentRoot to be unset on IntelliJ import

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

When I import from my build.gradle file into IntelliJ 14.0.2, if I specify the manifest.srcFile in a sourceSet then .iml is not generated and the contentRoot is never set -- basically there is no project, it is simply a list of files.

Has anyone has this issue?

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "0.01"
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    // all *.jar files in the libs dir
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    // remote dependencies
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The plugin you have applied is incorrect, hence no Android specific projects are set up. It should be:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```